# Selenium webdriver: verify multiple text in a page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I have a page which will give any one of the three messages (error, warning and success) on form submit.

The problem is only one message will be visible at a time and for the rest i am getting 'NoSuchElementException'.

My current code is:

```
String expectedWarningMessage = new String("Product details already present");
String expectedErrorMessage = new String("Case Id already exists. Please use 'Search DOA return form' to modify authorization details.");
String expectedSuccessMessage = new String("The DOA Authorisation has been sent successfully.");

String actualWarningMessage = getWebElement("apj.newdoa.warning.message").getText().trim();         
String actualErrorMessage = getWebElement("apj.newdoa.error.message").getText().trim();    
String actualSuccessMessage = getWebElement("apj.newdoa.success.message").getText().trim();

if (actualWarningMessage.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedWarningMessage)) {
        logger.info("success");
        getWebElement("apj.newdoa.warning.yesbutton").click();
}else if(actualErrorMessage.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedErrorMessage)) {
        logger.info("fail");
}else if (actualSuccessMessage.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedSuccessMessage)) {
        logger.info("success");
} else {
        logger.info("Something went Wrong");
}
```

Please note that, all the three texts appear at different places on the DOM so the locators for the texts are different.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this. One method is to use a `try-catch` as many often suggest. This is not a best practice and is recommended against in the Selenium Java docs.

Another method is to use `driver.findElements()` and check to see if the collection is empty to determine whether an element exists or not. This is the recommended method in the [Selenium Java docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-).

> findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.

Your specific case has a different approach that can be used that is more efficient. Since your CSS selector is of the `"apj.newdoa.*.message"` format, you can skip the class that indicates the message type and always find the message element. This lets us avoid detecting the specific error message element 3 times. In this case, we can use `"apj.newdoa.message"` and always find the message. After we've found the message element, we then need to determine which class it contains because that indicates the message type: success, warning, or error. We can do that by pulling the `class` attribute and doing a text cotnains search. Once we've done all this, we know which message to expect and can then just `Assert` it's expected value. (NOTE: The `Assert` class comes from JUnit and TestNG, see #3 below.)

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("apj.newdoa.message"));
if (e.getCssValue("class").contains("success"))
{
    expectedMessage = expectedSuccessMessage;
}
else if (e.getCssValue("class").contains("warning"))
{
    expectedMessage = expectedWarningMessage;
}
else if (e.getCssValue("class").contains("error"))
{
    expectedMessage = expectedErrorMessage;
}
else
{
    Assert.fail("The expected message was not found");
}

Assert.assertEquals(expectedMessage, e.getText().trim(), "Verify expected message");
```

A few additional points.

1. There's no need to pass a known string to the `String()` constructor, it's already a `String`, just assign it, e.g.

   ```
   String expectedWarningMessage = "Product details already present";
   ```
2. Don't create a function to get an element. There's no need.

   ```
   getWebElement("apj.newdoa.warning.yesbutton");
   ```

   is no more efficient than

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("apj.newdoa.warning.yesbutton"));
   ```

   but in your case you have to write the wrapper function and then make sure that it doesn't contain bugs. Not to mention, anyone else using your code has to learn your API instead of the standard Selenium API provided. If you must have that function, it should accept a `By` class instead of a `String` so that it's more flexible (not restricted to only CSS selectors and you don't have to parse the string to figure out what type it is or test all the different methods, etc. that I've seen people try to do.)

   ```
   WebElement getWebElement(By locator)
   {
       return driver.findElement(locator);
   }
   ```
3. Don't write your own logging mechanism. Use one of the existing, tested libraries like JUnit or TestNG. They have a lot of functionality and are reliable because so many people use them.

Comment: There is slight misrepresentation on my part, the method getWebElement("apj.newdoa.warning.message") is reading a key from object repository (properties file) and its not a css locator, so the key maps to a actual locator (can handle all the locator types like id, xpath, css, etc). And also the locators for all the three messages are different. So i cant use the above approach. Please suggest some other solutions.

Comment: Then you need to rewrite your question and provide all the details necessary to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

In case you stick to your logic, one approach could be "Wrap your `getWebElement` with `try`-`catch` and catch `NoSuchElementException`

```
String actualWarningMessage;
try
{ 
    actualWarningMessage  = getWebElement("apj.newdoa.warning.message").getText().trim();         
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e)
{
}
```